# How do I set up a deploy to server / sync with server goal in Maven?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, maven, synchronization

I'd running maven locally, and it's fantastic! The only issue that I have now is that I have a heavy stack and I have these Massive WAR files. Is there a good approach or best practice with regards to using Maven as a tool to sync your local dependencies with application running on the server?

For example, can I somehow create a goal that uploads the POM, and tells Maven to rebuild on the server side? We're running linux on both sides. Jetty locally and Tomcat remotely.

I'm sure the Apache guys thought of this... Your thoughts are much appreciated...

Comment: We're using SVN too... But thinking of switching to Mercurial (if Maven and SVN integrate)

Comment: Why would you want to rebuild anything at the server-side? You have your war already built. Just deploy it on the server. No need for a rebuild.

Comment: My WAR's are 100MB and our servers are on the other side of the world. It takes a while to upload which is a pain if you're doing server-side debugging or maintenance.

Comment: Then have a working copy of your sources on the server, and build the war on the server. I don't see why you'd want anything special from Maven to do that. Your sources are in a VCS (SVN, Git, whatever), right?

Answer (score 2):

One tool you could look into is [cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin), which can take the generated artifact that you've built and install it to a remote server instance.  Cargo can be integrated into your maven build.

However, if you have multiple developers and just want the latest version of whatever is in the repository deployed to the server, I'd encourage you to at least investigate a continuous integration server and setting up a manual or nightly job to do deployments for you.  A continuous integration server, such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), can:

1. Check SVN for any code changes (if you want to enable SVN polling)
2. Perform a checkout (or revert + update) to receive the latest code from SVN.
3. Build the WAR file using your maven build.
4. Use either the Jenkins Deploy Plugin or a post build step to deploy the final WAR.  Letting Cargo do the deploy via maven during the build is also an option.

Just some thoughts.  I also highly recommend Nexus as an artifact repository.  Since Jenkins is able to run your build as a Maven build, you can configure Jenkins to run the deploy goal and configure maven with the location of your deployed artifacts server (Nexus location) for the builds to be pushed to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way would be to install the resulting war (if neccessary one per server config) into a repository (not SVN, a Maven repository like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)). With that you can setup simple scripts or maven configs to deploy the artifacts on your test or production servers without the need to rebuild them on the server.

Checkout the [install plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/).